# Given that $x\geqslant 0$,how do I show that this function is discontinuous?

Tags: limits, functions

$$ f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}+x}{x^n+2} $$
Since I'm required to also draw a graph for this function,is it possible for me to denote $n=1$ and solve it?
If not,I have no idea how I'm supposed to prove it by epsilon-delta

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. Posting links to images is inconvenient for readers now and useless for people doing searches on MSE in the future. As for the mathematics, try dividing through by $x^n$ and using the rules for sums, products and quotients of limits.

Comment: $n$ is limit's bound variable and you cannot set it to $1$. Better is to consider cases less and more, then $1$ and follow previous comment advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with $n=1$ since $f(x)$ is a limit as $n\rightarrow +\infty$, it does not involve $n$ at the end. The key point is to know what is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x^n$, the limit is $0$ if $x<1$, $1$ if $x=1$ and $+\infty$ if $x>1$, therefore $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ if $x<1$, $f(1)=\frac{2}{3}$, as for $x>1$, dividing by $x^n$ gives that $\frac{x^{n+1}+x}{x^n+2}=x\frac{1+x^{-n}}{1+2x^{-n}}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}x$, therefore $f(x)=x$. I think you can finish from here.

Comment: @Anurag A. In OP is restriction $x \geqslant 0$.

Comment: @zkutch Oh yes!!. I was reading the question and didn't look at the title.